# How to Auto-populate a role in DNN?

Tags: dotnetnuke

When a user registers on my DNN site I want them to automatically be assigned to a default role. How can I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a role there is a checkbox called 'Auto Assignment' - by checking this users who register are automatically added to this role.

Answer (score 0):

first You need to define the roles and assign them by using the AddUserToRole Method of the role controller.